# What plant is this? It's definitely not a cactus

Tags: identification

I recently bought a small plant from a greenhouse.  The label on the plant said it was an "Old Man of the Andes", but a quick google search shows that is a cactus, and this is clearly not a cactus.  Any help in identifying this would be appreciated, because I definitely don't want to kill it by accident! [image]

Comment: Did you google the Latin name? From what I can see it isn't the latin name for the old man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [Crassula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula) species. Probably a cultivar of [*Crassula ovata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula_ovata), maybe  [*Crassula ovata* 'Gollum'](http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/crassula-ovata-gollum/).

Comment: Looking online, that seems right, although this doesn't have any wooden stems... would they appear later as this plant grows larger?

Comment: @user1203054 Yes, the young plants will not have the woody stems. These will appear as the lowest leaves die off, when the plant is older. The more one of these has grown, the longer the stems will be.